# Variation of action with vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, vector-fields, action, variational-calculus

Assume an action
$$
S= \int{d^2x \;\vec{v}\cdot(\partial_\mu\vec{v}\times\partial_\nu\vec{v}})\;\epsilon^{\mu\nu}
$$
where $\vec{v}$ a 3-vector field $\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3$) and $\epsilon^{\mu\nu}$ the 2-dimensional levi-civita tensor

How can I calculate the variation in $\vec{v}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/548038/2451

Comment: Sorry, I should've updated that. Instead I deleted to rewrite the question.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple in the present case it to rewrite the expression in following form:
$$
S = \int \varepsilon^{i j k} v_i \partial_\mu v_j \partial_\nu v_k 
$$
And take the variation with respect to $v_i$:
$$
\delta S = 3 \int \varepsilon^{i j k} \delta v_i \partial_\mu v_j \partial_\nu v_k 
$$
Where the 2 in the total factor of 3 come from integrating by parts, and relabeling the indices, here i assumed, that integral vanishes on boundary

Comment: But the partials are with respect to the field not the spacetime coordinates.